# FBSDKShareKit.h' file not found xcode unity

Tags: xcode, facebook, unity-game-engine

im trying to build unity project to ios device

everything was working good before i installed FaceBookSDK

now i always get this error:

[image: error]

i was trying some solutions over the internet including [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-sdk-for-unity/issues/578)
none of them helped me

unity 2020.3.18f1
FacebookSDK 11.0.0

any help?

Comment: Do you really need the Facebook SDK in your project? Their sdk for Unity is total garbage.
Getting it to run on iOS is usually not too bad, but on Android it is a nightmare. Be prepared for a solid week of asking around on forums to find the current awful hacky workaround to get it to run.

Comment: actually it works on android without problems.. and yes i want facebook account link so i must use facebook sdk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an issue occurs when using Facebook SDK above 11.1.0,
all you have to do is downgrade the SDK to 11.1.0,
Open the pod file as notepad or on Xcode and change the pod Script for Facebook SDK

replace this

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 11.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics', '~> 11.0'
  pod 'FBSDKGamingServicesKit', '~> 11.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 11.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 11.0'
```

to this

```
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 11.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit_Basics', '~> 11.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKGamingServicesKit', '~> 11.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 11.1.0'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit', '~> 11.1.0'
```

Comment: thanks for answer, it was part of the solution. i had to do also the steps i mentioned in my answer to post

Comment: your welcome, your steps necessary for the pod update, when updating pods the terminal pops up a message that says you should use Xcode workspace to open your project.
please consider accepting the answer if it work for you.

Answer (score 1):

finally i fixed it using [this](https://forum.unity.com/threads/ios-framework-addition-failed-due-to-a-cocoapods-installation-failure.483511/)

the solution:

1- Open terminal and open project output folder (cd [folder path])

2- I run the code "pod install", it created the xcworkscape file.

3- I open the xcworkspace file in xcode and it works without error on device